# Getting a specifit string from a text using bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, clearcase

I have an output that look like this:

```
Tag: abrodov_linux_vlsi07_test1
  Global path: /net/vposeidon02/vlsifs/vlsi02/vlsi_ccstore/07/abrodov/abrodov_linux_vlsi07_test1.vws
  Server host: ta1vlsi07
  Region: tlv_unix
  Active: YES
  View tag uuid:26075e8c.4e2e11e4.9cc0.a4:ba:db:3c:fc:0e
View on host: ta1vlsi07
View server access path: /net/vposeidon02/vlsifs/vlsi02/vlsi_ccstore/07/abrodov/abrodov_linux_vlsi07_test1.vws
View uuid: 26075e8c.4e2e11e4.9cc0.a4:ba:db:3c:fc:0e
View owner: abrodov
```

I need to get th server host which is in this example is `ta1vlsi07`

I wrote some command that worked for in order to get the View uuid, but in this case it didn't work, here is the command:

```
ct lsview -l abrodov_linux_vlsi07_test1 |grep -i 'Server host:' | cut -d" " -f3
```

the output that i get is `Server` instead of the host name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in a single grep command if it supports `-P` parameter.

```
ct lsview -l abrodov_linux_vlsi07_test1 | grep -oP 'Server host:\s*\K\S+'
```

**Explanation:**

- `Server host:`  Matches the string `Server host:`
- `\s*` Matches zero or more spaces.
- `\K` Discards the previously matched characters from getting printed. So in our case `Server host:` plus the following spaces got discarded.
- `\S+` Now the following one or more non-space characters would be matched and printed out.

Comment: Can you explain to me please what does `\s*\K\S+` mean

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the leading spaces at the begining of the line

use

```
ct lsview -l abrodov_linux_vlsi07_test1 |grep -i 'Server host:' | cut -d" " -f5
```

will produce output

```
ta1vlsi07
```

Also if you are not always sure of the number of leading spaces then use

```
 ct lsview -l abrodov_linux_vlsi07_test1 | grep -o 'Server host:.*' | cut -d" " -f3
```

`-o` option selects the matched part in the string

Answer (score 1):

In case if need a shorter and more faster version of the command you can use `awk`

```
 $ ct lsview -l abrodov_linux_vlsi07_test1 | awk '/Server host:/ {print $3}'
```